# In a Inventory - type Android App, I cannot display the room database

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room, android-databinding

The app is in development and it can be found here:
https://github.com/toaderDragos/GlycemicApp

So, why can't I see the database? In the App inspection, the fields are populating but not showing.
Later, each row will have a button/ edit text field, and upon insertion will calculate live some numbers.
I am sure the mistake is rookie like but I couldn't find it for many hours.
I have no errors shown, but no text either.
UX/UI is still a work in progress.

Thank you very much!

Comment: "In the App inspection, the fields are populating but not showing." what do you mean by that?

Comment: They are not showing in the recycler view when I run the app!

Answer (score 0):

Your Data is successfully inserted into your database see here

[image]

See Your database and go to `App inspection`

[image]

Comment: yes here they are shown, I meant that when I run the app, the recyclerView does not take the values from the database and does not show them

Comment: Well that seems like a problem not with the database, but in your implementation of taking the data from it, could you share your recycler view code ( and possibly the view model that takes the data "out"?)

Comment: ViewModel is here: https://github.com/toaderDragos/GlycemicApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/dragos/glycemic/GlycemicViewModel.kt

Comment: recyclerView adapter: https://github.com/toaderDragos/GlycemicApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/dragos/glycemic/ItemListAdapter.kt

Answer (score 0):

The error in this specific case was that I was using a style for each item in the recyclerView that was preventing the room database to be shown. I deleted the style for each item in the XML and it started working.